# Botones dinámicos

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

no sé si el título será el correcto pero requiero hacer lo siguiente:

Tengo la siguiente **tabla** cargada con la información proveniente de una API.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi **paises.component.ts** tengo el siguiente código que se encarga de cargar en el DataTable mi información.

```
    async ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.paises = await this.obtenerPaises();

    this.paises.forEach(function (value) {
      value.pais_acciones = '<center>';
      value.pais_acciones += '<button (click)=\'fnEliminarMantenedor()\' type="button"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>';
      value.pais_acciones += '</center>';
    });

    this.fn_cargarTablaPaises(this.paises);
}

fn_cargarTablaPaises(json) {
    this.dtOptions = {
      data: json,
      fixedHeader: {
        header: true,
        footer: true
      },
      language: {
        sProcessing:     'Procesando...',
        sLengthMenu:     'Mostrar _MENU_ registros',
        sZeroRecords:    'No se encontraron resultados',
        sEmptyTable:     'Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla',
        sInfo:           'Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros',
        sInfoEmpty:      'Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros',
        sInfoFiltered:   '(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)',
        sInfoPostFix:    '',
        sSearch:         'Buscar:',
        sUrl:            '',
        sInfoThousands:  ',',
        sLoadingRecords: 'Cargando...',
        oPaginate: {
            sFirst:    'Primero',
            sLast:     'Último',
            sNext:     'Siguiente',
            sPrevious: 'Anterior'
        },
        oAria: {
            sSortAscending:  ': Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente',
            sSortDescending: ': Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente'
        }
      },
      pageLength: 25,
      responsive: true,
      dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
      buttons: [
        {extend: 'excel', title: 'Paises'},
        {extend: 'pdf', title: 'Paises'}
      ],
      columns: [
        {
          title: 'Pais',
          data: 'pais_nombre'
        },
        {
          title: 'Acciones',
          data: 'pais_acciones',
          width: '10%'
        }
      ]
    };

    this.dataTable = $(this.table.nativeElement);
    this.dataTable.DataTable(this.dtOptions);
  }
```

En **pais_acciones** estoy intentando hacer que ese **botón** realice algo, en este caso particular es mostrar el siguiente **console.log**

```
 public fnEliminarMantenedor() {
    console.log('entre al eliminar');
  }
```

Más adelante intentaré hacer que este botón abra un **modal** para poder modificar el nombre del país según el **id** que viene desde la API, de momento en mi *aprendizaje* sólo deseo mostrar un mensaje.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

*Entiendo que el problema radica en la creación de mi botón, pero no sé si he googleado mal pero no logro solucionarlo, gracias de antemano por la ayuda.*